# HP Pavilion HPE h8-1010 -- Dual Monitor Capable?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion

I'm looking into purchasing a HP Pavilion h8-1010, and I'm hoping that someone would be able to confirm that it will be able to support Dual monitors out-of-the-box?

The online store from where I will probably purchase it lists this under video port details:

```
1 DVI, 1 HDMI, 1 VGA via dongle
```

I'm unsure if the HDMI and the DVI will be able to run simultaneously, and/or what a "VGA via dongle" is.

Here's the place I'm looking to purchase it from:
[ECOST](http://www.ecost.com/p/6921844?source=EWBGOOGLEBASE&CAWELAID=1084452572)

And HP's support page on it (though it wasn't too helpful):
[HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02838702&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5097929#N352)

Does anyone know if this will support two monitors, and what kinds of additional adapters will have to be purchased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the page you [link](http://www.ecost.com/p/6921844?source=EWBGOOGLEBASE&CAWELAID=1084452572)

> AMD Radeon HD 6450 graphics card with 512MB DDR3 dedicated memory,
>   DVI, (VGA via dongle), and HDMI capabilities and support for one or
>   **two monitors** and Microsoft® DirectX 11

You can run 1 DVI and 1 HDMI monitor at the same time with the [6450](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125378). You can also note that DVI and HDMI are essentially the same signal except that (most of the time) DVI does not support *audio*

The "VGA via dongle" means you'd have to get a DVI-to-VGA dongle to run a VGA monitor, but there are ultimately 2 video ports for you to use. You'll be able to dual-screen the crap out of your desk

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. And I guess it would have payed to read the whole page. My instincts always send me to the specs page. :P

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @musketeer925 not wasted time at all, sometimes it's helpful to have a second (or third) set of eyes on something!